# Node : Node.exe crashes on Windows 2008 after about two weeks

Tags: windows, node.js, express

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) server, running on Windows 2008, crashes every two weeks or so. The node server is run as a service using [nssm](http://nssm.cc/)- there is no appreciable load on the server and logs dont provide any information, we've instrumented the service using [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston), but so far nothing in the application logs, or Windows event logs. The symptom is that the nssm service stays up, but the node.exe that it spawned dies, thereby denying service to clients.

This https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2840 seemed like a likely fix, but we've been able to reproduce the crash again with the suggested fix. We could just move it to a *nix box and get out of dodge, annoying at this point. If possible I'd really like to get this to work on Windows if possible. Hopefully the community has some ideas.

Comment: What about memory usage ?

Comment: negligible, checked that, cpu and memory are flat over the period.

Comment: do you monitor for unhandled exceptions ?

Comment: yes, that's the winston piece, got exception handlers everywhere. we specially increased our instrumentation when we first saw this error thinking it would help us - but no dice. Thats why stumped.